# Save button click event of Android app in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino-esp8266

[My app is connected but not getting updated as in this picture you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EA3l.jpg) I'm a newbie in Android application development. I want to save and retrieve my button click events in Firebase. My Android code for button click is:

```
View.OnClickListener btnOnOffClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String onoff="";

           switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.living_btn:
                    if (click ==0){
                        click=1;
                        onoff = "/SWITCH-01=ON";
                        living_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.livingroom);
                    }else{
                        click=0;
                        onoff = "/SWITCH-01=OFF";
                        living_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.livingroom_off);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.kitchen_btn:
                    if (click ==0){
                        click=1;
                        onoff = "/SWITCH-02=ON";
                        kitchen_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.kitchen);
                    }else{
                        click=0;
                        onoff = "/SWITCH-02=OFF";
                        kitchen_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.kitchen_off);
                    }
                    break;
               case R.id.bedroom1_btn:
                   if (click ==0){
                       click=1;
                       onoff = "/SWITCH-03=ON";
                       bedroom1_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bed_room);
                   }else{
                       click=0;
                       onoff = "/SWITCH-03=OFF";
                       bedroom1_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bed_room_off);
                   }
                   break;
               case R.id.bedroom2_btn:
                   if (click ==0){
                       click=1;
                       onoff = "/SWITCH-04=ON";
                       bedroom2_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bedroom2);
                   }else{
                       click=0;
                       onoff = "/SWITCH-04=OFF";
                       bedroom2_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bedroom2_off);
                   }
                   break;
               case R.id.bathroom_btn:
                   if (click ==0){
                       click=1;
                       onoff = "/SWITCH-05=ON";
                       bathroom_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bathroom);
                   }else{
                       click=0;
                       onoff = "/SWITCH-05=OFF";
                       bathroom_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bathroom_off);
                   }
                   break;
               case R.id.toilet_btn:
                   if (click ==0){
                       click=1;
                       onoff = "/SWITCH-06=ON";
                       toilet_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toi_on);
                   }else{
                       click=0;
                       onoff = "/SWITCH-06=OFF";
                       toilet_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toi_off);
                   }
                   break;
            }
```

Can I add the `v.getID` for the "database reference" and "set value" to `onoff` (variable)? If not, then how can I add the button click data? Also, how to retrieve the data through "data change" event.

Please help.

Comment: Where you are saving it in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Maintain each Button Name's in the Firebase Database as nodes and maintain a child named as "clicked" under each Button-node as a boolean variable 'true' for ON and 'false' for OFF.and start updating those nodes based on your switch position.

```
       Button living_btn = findViewById(R.id.your_btnId);
            Button kitchen_btn  = findViewById(R.id.your_btnId);
            ...
            //declare all your buttonViews...

            //attach the click listener to all buttons u just created like this...

             kitchen_btn.setOnClickListener(btnOnOffClickListener );
            living_btn.setOnClickListener(btnOnOffClickListener );
                //Creating a Reference to Buttons Node in Firebase DB for changing switch positions.
     final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    final DatabaseReference buttons = database.getReference("Buttons");

                 HashMap<String,Object>detailsUpdate = new HashMap<>();
                View.OnClickListener btnOnOffClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String onoff="";

                           switch(v.getId()){
                                case R.id.living_btn:
                                    if (click ==0){
                                        click=1;
                                          detailsUpdate.put("clicked",true);
                             buttons.child("living_btn").updateChildren(detailsUpdate);
                                        onoff = "/SWITCH-01=ON";
                                        living_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.livingroom);
                                    }else{
                                        click=0;
                                        onoff = "/SWITCH-01=OFF";
                           detailsUpdate.put("clicked",false);
                             buttons.child("living_btn").updateChildren(detailsUpdate);
                                        living_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.livingroom_off);
                                    }
                                    break;

                               // continue this for everyButton......


           }
//Code for retreiving the button states
  final DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("Buttons");
ref.child("living_btn").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String clicked = childSnapshot.getKey();
if(clicked.equalsIgnoreCase("clicked")){
boolean clicked = Boolean.parseBoolean(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
//u will get clicked as true or false and then use the info for further coding
}
}
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


        });
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133619/discussion-on-answer-by-roy-save-button-click-event-of-android-app-in-firebase).

Comment: @Roy Can we declare the hashmap in onClick event ?

Comment: Yes obviously we can..!! @Rachita

Comment: @Roy I'm sorry for being so dumb, but I didn't understand your this comment "//u will get clicked as true or false and then use the info for further coding"

Comment: I mean the boolean variable "clicked" u will get it as true or false depending upon what u hav stored in the database or in other words u will get the button state which u saved in the firebase database..!!!

Comment: the code is not updating, is there any other way to fix it

Comment: First of all Check if ur app is connected to the Database or not??

Comment: U may have imported all the gradle files but yet there would be a case where ur app is not yet connected to the Live Firebase Database.Run a test code by keeping a button and create a reference to ur main node and then try to update the node with a sample data(for e.g a simple String).

Comment: Did u manually create the main node "Buttons"  in the Firebase Database????

Comment: @Roy please check the link in my question and no I have not created any node in my database

Comment: can u post the pic of ur Firebase Database??

Comment: Click on the Expand button and create a main node called "Buttons" in it and attach a dummy data to it..Without creating a Root Node how can u possibly connect to the Firebase database,with a code having "Buttons" as it's reference,Sounds funny???

Comment: I have attached the sample Firebase DB screenshot in my answe,Ur database must look somewhat like that

Comment: Thank you sooooooo muuchhhh !!!!!! you have been very patience... great help, means a lot to me !!I'm able to save the data now

Comment: No problem.. Start Learning and be Patient,U will find the solution sometime or the other,Patience really matters in professional coding..!! Happy Coding!!!! @Rachita

Comment: Retrieving is an issue :( the datasnapshot is not recognized also do I have to code for individual buttons the same way ?

Comment: No need of writing individual button code,First try to print the datasnapshot using Log.e("datasnapshot",datasnapshot.toString()); and then look at the output in the logcat window.and make sure the data is coming.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot run my code in android studio I have to build the apk and install it on my phone to check if I'm right.  log's don't work

Comment: Which IDE are u using??@Rachita

Comment: or u can take a dummy text view in ur xml and print datasnapshot.toString(); in it and look at the data which u get.use a ,for loop which loops through all the datasnapshot children in ur case it is "clicked" and it retreives the button clicked status of all buttons but ur main reference on which u query must point to the main node (i.e Buttons i guess) in ur case

Comment: android studio 2.2.3, and laptop is lenovo, with 2 gb RAM. Could you please help me with retrieving too.

Comment: My java is quite weak, I didn't get what you trying to tell me an example would help. Sorry for inconvenience.